# can't close the Navigation drawer after clicking in a listview

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Everything was working perfectly before i tried to add a drawer toggle i just want to close the navigation drawer when i click to an item in the list : Everything was generated with android studio template

Main activity

```
public class Nav extends ActionBarActivity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nav);

        //mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
        //        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();


        //mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
        //        R.id.navigation_drawer,
        //        (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name) {};

        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        Fragment obj= null;
        ListFragment listfragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                listfragment= new F1_fr();
                break;
            case 1:
                obj= new F6_fr();
                break;
            case 2:
                obj= new F3_fr();
                break;
            case 3:
                obj= new F4_fr();
                break;
            case 4:
                obj= new F5_fr();
                break;



        }
        if (obj != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, obj)
                    .commit();
        }
        else if (listfragment != null) {
            // do stuff if its a listfragment
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, listfragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
                break;
            case 2:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
                break;
            case 3:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
                break;
            case 4:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section4);
                break;
            case 5:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section5);
                break;
            case 6:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section6);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }


    /*@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.nav, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }*/

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nav, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            ((Nav) activity).onSectionAttached(
                    getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

Layout:

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.gweltaz.coffy3.Nav">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
         android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
    <!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. -->
    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="com.example.gweltaz.coffy3.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Fragment :

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

    /**
     * Remember the position of the selected item.
     */
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

    /**
     * Per the design guidelines, you should show the drawer on launch until the user manually
     * expands it. This shared preference tracks this.
     */
    private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";

    /**
     * A pointer to the current callbacks instance (the Activity).
     */
    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;

    /**
     * Helper component that ties the action bar to the navigation drawer.
     */
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerListView;
    private View mFragmentContainerView;

    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated awareness of the
        // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }

        // Select either the default item (0) or the last selected item.
        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // Indicate that this fragment would like to influence the set of actions in the action bar.
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectItem(position);


            }
        });
        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                new String[]{
                        getString(R.string.title_section1),
                        getString(R.string.title_section2),
                        getString(R.string.title_section3),
                        getString(R.string.title_section4),
                        getString(R.string.title_section5),

                }));
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
        return mDrawerListView;
    }

    public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    /**
     * Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the navigation drawer interactions.
     *
     * @param fragmentId   The android:id of this fragment in its activity's layout.
     * @param drawerLayout The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.
     */
    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.whiteindic2,             /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to prevent auto-showing
                    // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                    sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
                }

                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce them to the drawer,
        // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }

        // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (mDrawerListView != null) {
            mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar. See also
        // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the action bar.
        if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
            showGlobalContextActionBar();
        }
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_example) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Example action.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Per the navigation drawer design guidelines, updates the action bar to show the global app
     * 'context', rather than just what's in the current screen.
     */
    private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    }

    private ActionBar getActionBar() {
        return ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    }

    /**
     * Callbacks interface that all activities using this fragment must implement.
     */
    public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
        /**
         * Called when an item in the navigation drawer is selected.
         */
        void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the `setup()` method is commented out in your MainActivity.  This is the method that defines what `fragmentId` to use when handling drawer operations in your navigation drawer fragment.

Uncomment the lines:

```
//mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
//  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
```

and

```
//mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
//        R.id.navigation_drawer,
//        (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
```

Comment: I know but if i do that i can't have my toggle arrow anymore

Comment: I think you have a conflict between your `ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;` defined in your MainActivity and the one automatically generated in your drawer fragment. The toggle in your drawer fragment should handle closing/opening operations.